# Remove authentication in custom REST API resource

Tags: 8

I have a custom module to create a custom Rest API resource. I want to remove the authentication and make it without required authentication.
In my file `custom_moudle/config/install/rest.resource.custom_resource.yml`

this is my code

```
id: custom_resource
plugin_id: custom_resource
granularity: method
configuration:
  GET:
    supported_formats:
      - json
    supported_auth:
      - basic_auth
```

This is working fine but with authentication. When trying to remove this lines

```
supported_auth:
  - basic_auth
```

I got an error. So what is the correct way to remove this authentication?

Answer (score 1):

REST module plugins must have an authentication plugin. Try using the `cookie` plugin, which is the default one that core uses.

Comment: There's not much to use. You just set it and it re-uses the default session cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the authentication for any rest API by Altering the route of that rest resource. there are various examples available on the web.

```
      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       */
      protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
        if ($route = $collection->get('rest.lost_password_resource.POST')) {
          $requirements = $route->getRequirements();
          if (!empty($requirements['_csrf_request_header_token'])) {
            unset($requirements['_csrf_request_header_token']);
            unset($requirements['_permission']);
            $options = $route->getOptions();
            unset($options['_auth']);
            $route->setOptions($options);
            $route->setRequirements($requirements);
          }
        }
     }
```